# Reuse Class File and Resources for Multiple Projects

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

**Background:**
I am currently developing an Android application that makes use of a custom dialog to prompt for a password.  Thinking ahead, I would like to be able to use this dialog (in its entirety) in my future projects with a minimum of configuration.

**Question:**
Is there any way I can encapsulate all of the code and XML for this dialog into one package?  Ideally, I would like to simply import the dialog and be done with it.  This is easy enough to do with the code, but I am not sure how to do this with the XML layout and string resources files.  Basically, I just don't want to have to manually add the string elements to my strings.xml file for each project as well as not have to copy (and thus duplicate) my layout.  I gave thought to hard-coding strings / layout into the code, but that seems like bad practice (even for only 4-5 strings and 2 textboxes).

So, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not write a library or framework for this sort of thing? That way, you can use your library in your future projects.

Comment: Yeah, that is roughly what I was after.  Didn't realize that the Android tools were one step ahead and already supported this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [library project](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject), that allows to share both code and resources.